# Decouple service invocation and database storage

Tags: rx-java

I have the following requirement :  query an external server in order to inform the result to a rest controller and at the same time save it to mongo . The thing is that with the implementation below when there is an mongo error the result is not return to rest controller. Is there any way to decouple both calls with rxJAva?

```
public Observable<LowestFareByProvider> lowestFareByProvider(final 
 FlightSearchRequest flightSearchRequest) {
                final FlightSpecification flightSpecification = FlightSpecification.builder()
                        .from(flightSearchRequest.getFrom())
                        .to(flightSearchRequest.getTo())
                        .departure(flightSearchRequest.getDeparture())
                        .build();

                return flightService.lowestFareByProvider(flightSpecification, flightSearchRequest.getProviders())
                        .map(it -> {
                            logger.debug("Saving to db in thread: {}", Thread.currentThread().getName());
                            return lowestFareByProviderRepository.save(it);
                        })
                        .flatMap(Single::toObservable);
            }
```

Comment: Could you please publish the interfaces for flightService and the Repository? Do you want to get callbacked, when the save to the db is through, or should it be a fire and forget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to eat up errors when Mongo save call fails and forward result to your subscriber.

```
public Observable<LowestFareByProvider> lowestFareByProvider(final 
 FlightSearchRequest flightSearchRequest) {
                final FlightSpecification flightSpecification = FlightSpecification.builder()
                        .from(flightSearchRequest.getFrom())
                        .to(flightSearchRequest.getTo())
                        .departure(flightSearchRequest.getDeparture())
                        .build();

                return flightService.lowestFareByProvider(flightSpecification, flightSearchRequest.getProviders())
                        .flatMap(result -> {
                            logger.debug("Saving to db in thread: {}", Thread.currentThread().getName());
                            return Observable.fromCallable(() -> { lowestFareByProviderRepository.save(result)})
                                             .onErrorReturn(result);
                        });
```

Please check syntax. Here, `onErrorReturn` ignores errors from Mongo save call (if any) and forwards result back to subscriber. And I removed `Single::toObservable` as you have `Observable` at this stage itself.